# Attempt at computing various values given a joint PDF

Tags: probability

Let the joint PDF of $(X, Y)$ be defined by

$$f(x, y) = \frac{c}{y} \text{exp}\left(-y -\frac{x}{y}\right) $$

for $x > 0$ and $y > 0 $

> (a) Determine the constant $c$
>
> (b) Find the marginal PDF of $Y$
>
> (c) Find the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y = y$
>
> (d) Compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Y = y]$

**(a)**

Ok, so using the fact that the sum of probability density functions equals $1$, I computed the value of $c$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
1 = c \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \text{exp}\left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} \\
= c\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty}\text{exp}\left(-y - \frac{x}{y} \right) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} \\
c\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{exp}(-y) \mathop{dy} \\
= c \\
\Longleftrightarrow \boxed{c = 1}
\end{align*}
$$

**(b)** I compute the marginal PDF of $Y$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x, y) \mathop{dx} \\
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \text{exp} \left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right) \mathop{dx} \\
= \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{exp}\left(-y - \frac{x}{y} \right) \mathop{dx} \\
= \frac{1}{y} \cdot y = 1,
\end{align*}
$$

but I'm pretty sure this is wrong. Can someone please check this part of the work for me? If it's right, then I'd have

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Y} = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_{Y}(x, y)} = \frac{1}{y} \text{exp} \left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
for $x, y > 0$ for part $(c)$.

**(d)**: To compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Y = y]$, we use the conditional pdf of $x$ given $Y = y$. So,

$$E[X^2 \mid Y = y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}\cdot \frac{\text{exp}(-x/y)}{y} \mathop{dx} = 2y^{2}$$

(I omitted the steps for integration).

Comment: When computing the marginal PDF you seem to have lost a factor of $\exp(-y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part $(a)$ is correct.

In part $(b)$ you have made a mistake whilst calculating the integral.

\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x, y) \mathop{dx} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \text{exp} \left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right) \mathop{dx} \\
&= \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{exp}\left(-y\right)  \text{exp}\left(-\frac{x}{y} \right) \mathop{dx} \\
&= \frac{\text{exp}(-y)}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{exp}\left( - \frac{x}{y} \right) \mathop{dx} \\
&= \frac{\text{exp}(-y)}{y} \cdot y \\
&= \text{exp}(-y).
\end{align*}

For part $(c)$ you would then have that

$$
f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_{Y}( y)} = \frac{\frac{1}{y} \text{exp} \left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right)}{\text{exp}(-y)} 
$$
which reduces to (I'll leave the details up to you)
$$f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac{\text{exp}(-x/y)}{y}.$$

Try and do part $(d)$.

Comment: Can you please check? I've updated my post.

Comment: Indeed, looks right to me!